# Why I am getting b' authentication failed error even if my username password are correct?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, gmail

Everytime, I am trying to login into my Gmail account using python script it always shows authentication failed . I have used the right username and password, My internet connection is stable and I have turned on the 'less secure app access' from gmail setting.

```
from imap_tools import MailBox

with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('sample@gmail.com', 'exm123') as mailbox:
    subjects = [msg.subject for msg in mailbox.fetch()]

mailbox = MailBox('imap.gmail.com')
mailbox.login('sample@gmail.com', 'exm123', initial_folder='INBOX')  # or mailbox.folder.set instead 3d arg
subjects = [msg.subject for msg in mailbox.fetch(AND(all=True))]

mailbox.logout()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ConnectionResetError: \[WinError 10054\] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (while accessing Gmail emails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52759754/connectionreseterror-winerror-10054-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-close)

Comment: Have you found solution?

Comment: hi, Vladimir thank for reacting , no I am still getting the error

Comment: You are using imap_tools right, problem not in it.